# Change image in dark mode

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I have a white image in a wave shape and its animated, and when the user open my site on mobile devices and enable dark mode the site will be dark but this image is still white

So my question is how can i solve this problem? like change the image if dark mode is enable or something else

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`<picture>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) element with your image. Inside the element add one or more `<source>` elements. These source element use a media query, like in CSS, to determine if the asset in the `srcset` should be used based on the media query.

In your case you could check the `prefers-color-scheme: dark` query to see if dark mode is enabled.

If it is not enabled then the *default* `src` on the image is used.
If it is enabled then the `srcset` on the `<source>` element will be used as the new value for the `src` on the image.

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="dark-image.jpg" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)">
  <img src="light-image.jpg" alt="Animated wave shape">
</picture>
```

Comment: I think `prefers-color-scheme: dark` work only on safari browser right?

Comment: Nope, support is pretty good. [caniuse prefers-color-scheme](https://caniuse.com/?search=prefers-color-scheme).